# Is it possible to Install one testing package by just modifying source.list file?

Tags: linux, debian, python, aptitude

I want to pick up Python3 from squeeze, meanwhile I would like to stay with lenny with all other packages.
Is this possible by just modifying source.list file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I took these steps:

1. Create /etc/apt/apt.conf file with this line below:(including the semicolon)

   APT::Default-Release "stable";
2. Change all 'lenny' to 'stable', and 'squeeze' to 'testing' in /etc/apt/source.list file;
3. After 'apt-get update' command, 'apt-get upgrade' command reported no upgrades as expected;
4. 'apt-cache search python3' worked fine now;
5. 'apt-get -t testing install python3' command installed python3 without any problems.

However, I do still have some issues:

1. Default-Release cannot be set to "lenny";
2. Default-Release can be set to '4.0' and '5.0*', but not '5.0';
3. These packages 'libncursesw5 libsqlite3-0 libssl0.9.8 and sqlite3' still got upgraded when I did 'apt-get -t testing install' command.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [instructions](http://wiki.debian.org/Backports) for enabling and using [backports](http://www.backports.org) in Debian.

Here is the [page for Python3](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python3).

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed python3 has not been included in lenny-backports. It is only in squeeze and sid. Is there any way to work around this?
Also, I cannot find /etc/apt/preferences file in my debian system.

Comment: -1 link-only answer (links aren't broken now, but could break in future)